# High latency observed while calling AWS sagemaker and online feature-store service

Tags: java, spring, amazon-eks, amazon-sagemaker, aws-sdk-java-2.0

We have recently done an integration with AWS SageMaker and FeatureStore for one of our use-case. On Cloudwatch, we could see the `p99: 50-60ms(Overhead + Model)` for sagemaker and `p99: 15-20ms` for feature-store.

But we are observing the high latencies while using JAVA AWS sdk 2.0, to call to feature-store, somewhat around. `p99: 180ms` for sagemaker and `p99: 100ms` for feature-store.

We have the containerised spring-boot application running on EKS and here we are calling FS and SM.

Sample code :-

**feature-store call**

```
   private static SageMakerFeatureStoreRuntimeClient featureStoreRuntimeClient;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ClientOverrideConfiguration clientOverrideConfiguration = ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                .apiCallTimeout(Duration.of(featureStoreConfig.getApiCallAttemptTimeout(), ChronoUnit.MILLIS))
                .retryPolicy(RetryPolicy.builder().numRetries(0).build())
                .build();

        featureStoreRuntimeClient = SageMakerFeatureStoreRuntimeClient.builder()
                .overrideConfiguration(clientOverrideConfiguration)
                .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create())
                .region(Region.AP_SOUTHEAST_1).build();
 }
```

**Sagemaker call**:

```
private static SageMakerRuntimeClient sageMakerRuntimeClient;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    ClientOverrideConfiguration clientOverrideConfiguration = ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
            .apiCallTimeout(Duration.of(sageMakerConfig.getApiCallAttemptTimeout(), ChronoUnit.MILLIS))
            .retryPolicy(RetryPolicy.builder().numRetries(0).build())
    .build();

    sageMakerRuntimeClient = SageMakerRuntimeClient.builder()
            .overrideConfiguration(clientOverrideConfiguration)
            .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create())
            .region(Region.AP_SOUTHEAST_1)
            .build();
}
```

Using AWS java-sdk2 for SageMaker and feature-store.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>sagemakerruntime</artifactId>
  <version>2.20.26</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>sagemakerfeaturestoreruntime</artifactId>
  <version>2.20.26</version>
</dependency>
```

What could we possible cause for such a high latency ?

Comment: You mentioned, 15-20ms and 30-40ms in CloudWatch. What metrics are these?  What p99 latencies are you comparing to, is it end to end latency? How are you measuring it?

Comment: @MarcKarp, In cloudwatch for sagemaker we are using: p99 of `ModelLatency` and `OverheadLatency` metric as stated in the docs : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatch.html#cloudwatch-metrics-feature-store
And For feature-store we are using `Latency` metrics as mentioned.

Comment: How we are measuring the end to end p99 latency on application level for sagemaker and feature-store: `histogram_quantile(0.99, sum(rate(resilience4j_circuitbreaker_calls_seconds_bucket{name="awsSageMaker"}[1m])) by (le))` . and same query with method name awsFeatureMaker as well.. @MarcKarp.

Comment: No @AnishB. But I could try that. Which version of sdk < 2.0 would be more suitable here ?

Comment: Are you sure it's a dependency issue?

Comment: Because it can be that processing time for the data model that you are sending to sagemaker is taking time.. Just sayin

Comment: I don't think this is a dependency issue @AnishB.

Comment: @AnishB. how to reduce the processing time for the data model ?

Comment: Not sure. Need to check. Is your model big that you are sending to sagemaker?

Comment: The request payload type is json and it contains around 400 <key, value> pairs. It not that big, I guess. are you suggesting to use some compression algo here ?

Comment: @tusharRawat Not sure on that. 400 key value pairs is not at all small. Can you check one thing. Try to send the data model directly into AWS Sagemaker via AWS CLI without using your code and do a comparison of p99 with and without code to see for any difference.

Comment: @AnishB. How can p99 be measured from the AWS CLI, as there would be high changes that there's not going to be latent from there.

Comment: @tusharRawat Can you check whether or not there is a lower latency via CLI? To be sure.